# I want to designate a specific version for apt-upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

We would like to use the /etc/apt/sources.list file to fix the apt-upgrade to version 20.04.2.

My current file looks like this.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe

I think I'm getting a package info that 20.04.4, so I want to fix it to 20.04.2. What should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is *focal*, and it's the same regardless of upgrade level.  The .1, .2, .3 etc. is really an *arbitrary* figure that relates to the ISO level of upgrade, which is not what you appear to want. You've not explored your issue, but if it's HWE/kernel stack related; you can switch to use the GA or older kernel which doesn't change unlike the HWE kernel will (ie. 20.04 through 20.04.5 will all use the 5.4 kernel if using GA, unlike HWE where it changes), but your actual problem hasn't been specified.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412039/edit) to clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish that has led you to believe that "fixing" at 20.04.2 is a great idea?